# php mongodb validate form password

Tags: php, mongodb, hash

This is my first time using mongodb with php and I have a register and a login form . When a user registers I succesfully hash his password using `password_hash()` php function and insert it in a mongodb collection . However when I login and insert a password I want to check if inserted password corresponds to a hashed password in the collection using `password_verify()`

I cannot find the correct syntax to iterate through the collection and check if a hashed password matches with the given password when I login .

My code  :

```
<?php

 
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$m = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://127.0.0.1/");
$db = $m ->ECommerce;

$collection = $db->users;


if($_POST){

  $uname = $_POST['uname'];
  $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

  //which  is the second argument here ? I want to add the database password as argument 
  $cursor = $collection->find(array('password'=> password_verify($pwd ,...) ));

  foreach ($cursor as $doc){
      echo $doc["firstName"];
  }
  

}

?>
```

Comment: Give +1 because you save the hash value in your DB instead of the password as clear text. However, is it transmitted as clear text in the HTTP body? Apart from that you should [enable authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) at your MongoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to use the `password_verify()` function then I guess you have to run it like this:

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array('username' => $uname ));
foreach ($cursor as $doc){
   if ( password_verify($pwd, $doc["password"]) ) {
     echo $doc["firstName"];
   }
}
```

Or with a single query:

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array('username' => $uname, 'password' => password_hash($pwd) ));
```